# Plotting Points in R with Google Map context. Error in download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE)

Tags: r, google

I am trying to plot point data with Google Map context but i keep getting an Error. I tried the same using OSM context and it worked just fine.

## R Code below

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
Lat <- as.vector(quakes$lat)
Long <- as.vector(quakes$long)
MyMap <- MapBackground(lat=Lat, lon=Long, zoom = 10)
PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap,Lat,Long,cex=tmp+0.3,pch=1,
                col= '#FB6A4A80')
```

## Error Report

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-24.655,176.9&zoom=4&size=640x640&maptype=mobile&format=png32&sensor=true&key="
Error in download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-24.655,176.9&zoom=4&size=640x640&maptype=mobile&format=png32&sensor=true&key='
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(urlStr, destfile, mode = "wb", quiet = TRUE) :
  cannot open URL 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-24.655,176.9&zoom=4&size=640x640&maptype=mobile&format=png32&sensor=true&key=': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note the:

```
   HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

which makes me think you need an API key - google have recently changed their policy on this. Go get one, and then try:

```
 MyMap <- MapBackground(lat=Lat, lon=Long, zoom = 10, API_console_key="my-api-key-here-XXXXX")
```

Don't show your key in public code.